# Can you reference images from css without using relative paths?

Tags: css, playframework

I'd like to create a div with a background image css:

```
#mydiv {
  background-image:url('/public/images/foo.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Now, I can't use routes in css, so as a result I have to use a relative path, or my app will break if installed at a non-root path.

Is there a way around this? Something like

```
background-image:url('@{publicFolder}/images/foo.png');
```

I did find [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/u1ZMvKQkftE) from a year ago that claims it's impossible. Is this still the case?

**Edit**: I know I can inline the css in the page, that's not really an acceptable solution, but rather a work around.

Comment: What's wrong with relative paths?

Comment: @Pekka - relative paths (as in '../images/foo.png') are brittle. They can break if you change the route to this page. This might even be an external configuration, e.g. an Apache frontend acting as a reverse proxy, with mod-rewrite. An "absolute" path is more robust (it's "relative" to your app folder, but the rendered page contains an absolute path).

Comment: "They can break if you change the route to this page" not if you have a separate style sheet - relative paths in style sheets are always relative to the style sheet location, which shouldn't change *that* often, should it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way around /is/ possible.

The problem is that CSS files are static, so Play! does not do anything on them - except serving them to the clients.

Just make your css files into views, write a generic controller that takes the filename as a parameter and they will be served as Play! Templates.

something in the lines of (beware: PSEUDOCODE!):

ROUTE:

```
get /css/{filename}  Application.getCSS
```

CONTROLLER

```
class public void getCSS(filename)
{
     renderTemplate(filename);
}
```

Then in your css you can use any groovy template feature you want.
The installation path is available as [http.path in the conf](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#http.path)

This will be very inefficient though, so you will have to add nginx or similar frontend to do some caching and set high expiration values for those files.

I'm not sure if it's worth doing it *just to avoid relative paths*!

I definitely think that the relative path is better suited generic deployment, and you are more likely to break things with this dynamic absolute approach.

### A better overall deployment strategy

Anothe important point is that if you do like absolute URLs, there's no problem.
I actually do too.

But when I deploy my web applications (be them play!, django, pure wsgi, or whatever else) I always put a web frontend.

Usually nginx.

This means that your play framework will be an upstream server, and you can do everything you want with the URLs on your :80 port - and manage several services with subdomains or subfolders...

but when you access your play application on its own port(s) everything will be absolute.

Finally, if you were deploying Play! as a war I would have the feeling you have chosen the wrong framework or the wrong deployment pattern! But then your jboss or whatever other application webserver will do some magic on the subfolders...

Comment: @ripper234 ahah sorry I meant it in a generic way to show all possible situations, not meaning that was your deployment pattern!

Comment: @user1187534 - you need an application server, that otherwise you don't need, because it does not bring much added value and play already includes the same webserver. Also, play! 2 is not currently fully working on a java app server.

Answer (score 12):

Since the play framework compiles all the files in /public, I used the following statement in the css to acces background images.

```
background: url("/assets/images/my-image-background.jpg");
```

It worked for me so far, not sure if it's a good practice though! Hope it can be of help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

The path always goes from your stylesheet. So why don't you use relative paths?

Example, your css is in `/public/css/`, so your path in your css file has to be `../images`. That's it.

But maybe [less.css](http://lesscss.org) has something similiar you're looking for.

Comment: thank you. I always wondered if path url in css goes from index or css file.

Answer (score -2):

take a look at conf/routes file.

in it you will find the following something like

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

which means in order to access resources in the public folder,
you would use /assets in your url.

so in your css you do
url(/assets/images/myimage.png) 
and it will work.

Comment: css files are not parsed, but rather are served statically. If you app is deployed in a subfolder ("http.path" in application.conf), then your proposed path will just not work.

Comment: yes, css files are served statically. but so long as you set up routes.conf correctly and use corresponding url in your css, images should be served correctly.

Comment: and this is exactly how i am using background-image:url('...') in my project's css files

Comment: the [Assets controller](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Assets) is, to my knowledge, only available in play 2.0 (and we are talking about play 1.2.* here)...