# play framwork controller action call inside js-file

Tags: javascript, url, controller, playframework

I'm looking for a solution to call a controller method/action inside an external js-file, not inside html-file!

so I have a test.js file, which has a ajax call and I want to let play create the url like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "#{@Application.sendMail();/}", //i know it's not the right syntax but something like this
    .......
});
```

so I don't know how this works. thanks for your suggestions!

cheers,

Marco

Comment: Almost an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710474/ except you are talking of JS, and @ripper234 of CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js files are static files so it is not a good practice to put variables inside because you then loose browser and server caching.

In such a situation it is better to create a function in your js and call it from your html with the url as an argument

Answer (score 0):

As @SebCesbron say, it's usually not a very good idea; you can still do it though.

In order to do so, Play! must serve you JS file as a view, not as a static file.

Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8711690/422670 for more informations on how to do that.