# Stylesheet contents not used

Tags: html, css, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following reference to my css stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")' media="screen" />
```

The stylesheet is located at `/public/stylesheets/main.css`.

And has this content:

```
body {
   background-image: @routes.Assets.versioned("images/deer.jpg");
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but no image appears in the background.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you view the application in Chrome, do you get any errors in the Dev Tools console? And if not, can you check on the link tag in your document `<head>` to see if it's actually being outputted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public resources (assets) are not processing by the template engine, so

```
body {
   background-image: @routes.Assets.versioned("images/deer.jpg");
}
```

never processed.

Here is the similar question:

[Can you reference images from css without using relative paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710474/can-you-reference-images-from-css-without-using-relative-paths)

**Solutions**

1. Use the static path

   ```
   body {
      background: url("/assets/images/deer.jpg");
   }
   ```

   The `/assets` part depends on your `routes` setting, `/assets` is a default.
2. Write CSS in the template file, so it would be one that returns but your controller (not one in the public folder)

Comment: Looks at the update, the second solution is described in the link in the answer (btw, I always use first)